# AWS lambda : Passing data from custom authorizer to business lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using custom authentication (with custom authorizer) for accessing AWS lambda. The authorization process works fine. But I have a problem to transmit data (ex principalId) between the authorizer lambda and the business lambda. All my lambdas are developed in JS.
As explain in AWS doc, in the authorizer lambda, I add few simple fields (principalId in the code below) in context field of the Auth response. But in my business lambda, I am not able to get these fields. The AWS documentation talks about $context variable.

First, could you explain me if the **$context** variable is another variable or the same variable than the **context** variable received in parameter of the JS function?

Second, could you explain me how to get in my business lambda the data field (ex: principalId) provided by the authorizer?

Seb

Comment: To clarify the answer, it is not available in the context variable in the JS function. It is in the event. The event is just a JSON map matching either you rmapping template, or a default format for the 'proxy' integration.

Answer (score 6):

The policy document of the authorizer can be enriched with a context where you can put your custom data. That data will be provided to the business lambda via the event.

Here is an example of a policy document:

```
const policy = {
    context: {
        customKey: 'payload data',
      },
    policyDocument: {
        Statement: [{
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
            Effect: effect,
            Resource: resource,
        }],
        Version: '2012-10-17',
    },
    principalId: sub,
};
```

The context contains a "customKey" with payload data as a string.

The mapping template for your API then should look like this:

```
{
  "customKey": "$context.authorizer.customKey"
}
```

Finally in your business lambda you can access the value of your customKey via the event:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

console.log(event.customKey);

.
.
.
};
```

This should log "payload data" according to my example.

Notice that you cannot set a JSON object or array as a valid value of any key in the context map according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this using lambda proxy integration or do I have to map the rest of the request manually in order to get this data from the authorizer?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the `$context` variable you are referring to is the one available in the API Gateway mapping template. It is not equivalent to the `context` parameter of the business Lambda.

However, using the mapping template and its `$context` variable, you can build the `event` parameter of the business Lambda.

If the mapping template of your API endpoint looks like this:

```
{
  "principalId" : "$context.authorizer.principalId"
}
```

You should retrieve the `principalId` in the Lambda's `event` parameter.

Using the *passthrough* option, `principalId` should be available in `event.context['authorizer-principal-id']`. This is the default behavior when you create an endpoint.

---

References about mapping templates in the doc:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html#models-mappings-mappings
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Comment: How and where do you define the mapping template ?

Comment: Go to the endpoint definition and enter in the *Integration Request* section. Then in *Body Mapping Templates*, there are various options to define a generic integration or a specific one depending on the request content type.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alexis answer, principalId - is currently the only param which can be passed from custom authorizer to a Lambda (as of today). However, the workaround for passing custom params is to stringify JSON parameters into the principleId. The discussion on this matter is [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=232702)

Answer (score 0):

AWS APIGateway is having following tags in API definition.

```
1. End point name, method type
2. parameters
3. responses
4. x-amazon-apigateway-integration => under this "requestParameters" will be populatested with mapping data or any data with key value pair.
```

The [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html) will definitely help you.